# How to bind Vaadin Combobox to PropertyID

Tags: combobox, vaadin

I have a `ComboBox` with a List of Objects (`YFEnum`) as a `BeanItemContainer`. The class looks as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ENUM")
public class YFEnum  implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="EN_ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="EN_NAME")
    private String name;

    .....
```

In my form I would like to bind the ID of the `YFEnum`-Object via `FieldGroup.bindMemberFields` to a PropertyID. In my code I tried this as follows, but I know, this cannot work. Unfortunately, I don't know how it could work:

```
@PropertyId("art")
protected ComboBox cbArt;
```

The Entity where "art" is a Property looks as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PV_EDELMETALL")
@DiscriminatorValue("PVEdelMetall")
public class PVEdelMetall extends ProduktVereinbarung implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="PVEM_ART")
    protected int art;

    ....
```

How can I manage, to get the ID of the selected object (`YFEnum`) from the ComboBox to the PropertyID "art"?

Comment: do you expect the value of art to be one of the ids of YFEnum? Then why dont you model your entities accordingly with @OneToMany? Type of art will become YFEnum and mapping in vaadin will be a lot easier.

Comment: I'd like to query in the PVEdelMetall table over the YFEnum-ID without joining the table with YFEnum-Entities. Or do I understand your recommendation wrong?